# Need a BAT file to copy & rename all files in specific tree

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

I need to create a .bat that runs through a multilayered directory... copying certain files that contain the following suffix: '.full.jpg' to save as '.jpg'

What I've tried:

```
copy /y "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\*.full.jpg" "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\*.jpg"
```

However, I cannot get it to work.

The .bat is located in the 'maindir' directory and ran from the terminal (cmd).

Here's an example scenario that maps closely to mine:

Existing Files:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\a\picture1.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\a\picture3.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\b\picturea.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\b\pic1.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\a\foto.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\a\photo.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\b\pic1.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\c\pi2.full.jpg
```

Example Output Wanted:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\a\picture1.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\a\picture1.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\a\picture3.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\a\picture3.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\b\picturea.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\b\picturea.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\b\pic1.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\a\b\pic1.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\a\foto.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\a\foto.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\a\photo.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\a\photo.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\b\pic1.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\b\pic1.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\c\pi2.full.jpg
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir\b\c\pi2.jpg
```

I'd appreciate any help towards this as I haven't been able to do it yet. I will run across a directory structure whereby the top level directory will contain 15+ directories and each containing 20+ directories with 100+ files in each lowest directory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=u:\Users\myname\Desktop\maindir"
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.full.jpg) DO (
 FOR %%b IN ("%%~dpna") DO ECHO(COPY "%%a" "%%~dpnb.jpg"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The inner `for` examines the drive-path-name only of the complete filename in `%%a` (ie. it drops the `.jpg`) and delivers the drive-path-name of that name (ie. drops the `.full`) to which you add `.jpg` and job done.

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files.

Comment: Worked perfectly :) Thank you very much indeed!... The only additional alteration I made was to place the .bat in the main directory and modify the set source to: SET "sourcedir=%CD%"